# Каковы правила контракта между методами hashcode и equals

Tags: java, hashcode, equals

Есть тестовое задание с не единственным вариантом ответа:

> Какие правила контракта между hashCode() и equals()?
>
> 1) Если два объекта возвращают разные значения hashcode(), то они не могут быть равны
>   2) Если два объекта возвращают одинаковые значения hashCode(), значит они равны
>   3) Если два объекта не равны, то и hashCode() у них обязательно отличается
>   4) Если два объекта равны, то они должны возвращать одинаковое значение hashCode()

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в соответствии с правилами контракта верным является лишь ответ 4?

*Если объекты равны по результатам выполнения метода equals, тогда их hashcode должны быть одинаковыми.

**Если объекты не равны по результатам выполнения метода equals, тогда их hashcode могут быть как одинаковыми, так и разными. Однако для повышения производительности лучше, чтобы разные объекты возвращали разные коды.

Comment: А чем 1 не устраивает?

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрим простейший пример хэширования

```
x%2:  2%2 = 0; 4%2 = 0;
```

в данном случае хэш совпадает, но объекты не равны.

1. x = 2 всегда вернёт 0 - верно
2. в первом и втором случае хэши одинаковые - не верно
3. см. правило 2 - не верно
4. см. правило 1 - верно

Comment: Как из _"x = 2 всегда вернёт 0"_ следует, что первый пункт верен?

Comment: Потому что один и тот же объект всегда вернёт один и тот же хэш, если хэш другой, то объект не равен сравниваемому

Comment: Я не вижу связи между "**один** и тот же объект должен возвращать один и тот же хэш"  и "если **два** объекта возвращают разные хэши, то они не равны". Здесь нужно отталкиваться от первого правила в вопросе (потому что если `A -> B`, то `!B -> !A`), а не от того, что "если объект не менялся, то он должен продолжать возвращать один и тот же хэш".

Comment: Не понимаю, в чём проблема то? Одинаковые объекты не могут иметь разный хэш.

Comment: Про следствие тоже не понял, к чему оно? Идентично же.

Comment: Не могут. И ответ 1 верен, спору нет. Проблема только в том, как вы это обосновываете. В вопросе речь про **два** объекта в **общем** случае, а вы говорите про **один** объект в **конкретном** случае. Чтобы опровергнуть высказывание, достаточно конкретного случая когда это не так. Поэтому к вашему обоснованию неверности ответа 2 у меня претензий нет. А вот к первому - есть. И к самому обоснованию, и к тому что оно делается на частном случае.

Comment: Эм, понял, я размышлял так, в данном упрощённом варианте ответа, объект у нас один, пусть это будет 2, если мы возьмём ещё одну 2, то по сути это будет всё та же двойка. Если сказать `x=2; y=2`, хотя мы и сравниваем две переменных, но всё равно по сути они ссылаются на одно и то же значение.

Comment: Да, что с двойками всё будет верно - понятно сразу. Да и в целом ответ 1 звучит относительно очевидно. Однако чтобы строго доказать для общего случая, нужна как раз мат. логика и импликация в частности. Пусть А - "два объекта равны (equals)", а В - "два объекта имеют одинаковый хэш". В таком случае первое правило из вопроса - это `A -> B`. Так как `A -> B` = `!B -> !A` и первое правило верно, то верно и "если два объекта **не** имеют одинаковый хэш, то два объекта **не** равны".

Comment: А, ну да, если формально описывать, то так правильнее

Answer (score 1):

Обратимся к официальному источнику: на https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

The general contract of hashCode is:

Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.

If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

Из второго контракта можно судить, что правильный ответ 4, а 1 лишь следствие из него.

Answer (score 0):

Если хеш-коды равны это не обязательно гарантирует что объекты одинаковы.

Сто процентов, если хешкоды разные, то и объекты разные.

Из этого следует что 4 и 1 - верно.